# What does X[1:(n-2)] in R exactly do?

Tags: r, plot

I have a generated sequence `X`. For example:

```
7.289043e-05 7.771657e-01 6.623381e-01 9.795376e-01 9.161824e-01 6.812561e-01 8.418944e-01 9.200620e-01 9.433220e-01 3.793739e-01 7.863456e-01 3.037084e-01 7.451401e-01 7.374650e-01 7.185290e-01 6.739892e-01 
#... and so on...
```

Now I want to plot this sequence using the function `plot3d` in R.

Now, the sample solution is using:

```
n <- 10^5 #X length
plot3d(X[1:(n-2)], X[2:(n-1)], X[3:n])
```

I don't exactly understand what `X[1:(n-2)]`, `X[2:(n-1)]` and `X[3:n]` does.
Could someone explain me why we use this to plot it?

I've read the documentation of `plot3d` but I'm still clueless. Thanks.

Comment: what is `n` exactly? How it is defined?

Comment: Reading this will help - [Subsetting](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html)

Comment: @cccnrc n is a number. To be precise, it is 10^5.

Comment: ok but where does it come from? Basically `X[1:(n-1)]` means: subset of `X` starting from element at position `1` to element at position `n-1` (so penultimate if `n` is the total number of elements in the list)

Comment: @cccnrc Well, im generating two sequences of pseudo-random numbers with different parameters using a linear congurence generator I implemented in R. My function generates sequences of size n, which exactly this n is. Now I want to plot both sequences in 3D space to compare which set of parameters is more well-suited for generating pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: When you use plot3d, you are passing it 3 vectors which represent the x, y, and z coordinates of the points. Normally that would mean that you have a data frame with at least three continuous variables, and you want to choose three to visualize, perhaps for exploratory analysis. What doesn’t make sense about your code is that it seems like you have one vector which you’re using for all three coordinates, albeit with an offset. I can’t imagine what insights you could get from that visualization that you couldn’t get from a 2-D scatter plot.

Comment: What I fail to understand is, if you "implemented a linear congurence generator in R", how do you not know the very basic `x[]` subset operation, or `1:(n-1)` sequence generator?

Comment: @SymbolixAU I'm very new to R and writing a linear congurence generator is very easy if you know how the math works. This has nothing to do with subsetting or syntax of R. In fact I can show you my code:
`LCG = function(a,b,m,n,seed){ 
  X<-c(seed) 
  for (k in 1:n){
    X[k+1]<-((a*X[k]+b) %% m)
  }
  return(X)
}`. I simply didn't know any R syntax and just started with learning by doing. :)

Comment: You have `1:n`, and `X[k+1]` in your code. How was this "easy" to write, if you didn't know what those operations did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Some of the comment suffice, but here is a complete answer

The items `X[1:(n-2)]`, etc. do not have anything to do with the `plot3d()` function. they are merely variable you pass to the function.
Here, the first variable `plot3d()` expects is `x`, then `y`, then `z`. In other words, you are passing vectors of `x`, `y`, and `z` values that will wil used as 3D coordinates to the function.
To understand why `plot3d()` expects these variable in that order, look at the documentation or type `?plot3d` in R.

#### What do these values mean?

`X` is the sequence you created, which is a one-dimensional sequence of numbers, we like to call a 'vector'.
Using the `[]` subset command, you can extract certain values from your vector.
e.g. `x[1]` extracts the first value. Likewise, `x[1:10]` extracts values 1 through 10.

Furthermore, you define object `n`. You set is to be equal to the length of `X`. (You could also use `length(x)`).

So, when you use `X[1:(n-2)]` you take a subset of `X`, where you only keep the first until the 'n minus 2th' value of `X`.
`X[2:(n-1)]` keeps the second until 'n minus 1th' value.
`X[3:n]` keeps the third until nth value.

To summarize, you define the x, y and z coordinates of your 3D plot as subsets of `X`.